# Thrown exception pointing to xmemory0

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Within a static library I'm creating, I have a struct called `Vertex` that holds three variables used for an image drawn on a plane:

```
struct Vertex
{
    glm::vec2 Position;
    glm::vec3 Color;
    glm::vec2 TexCoord;
};
```

and a list of vertices like so (outside of the class):

```
const std::vector<graphics::Vertex> vertices =
        {
            { { -0.5f, -0.5f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f } },
            { { 0.5f, -0.5f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f } },
            { { 0.5f, 0.5f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f } },
            { { -0.5f, 0.5f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f } }
        };
```

When I run the program, I get a thrown exception and points to line 637 in xmemory0:

```
template<class _Objty,
class... _Types>
void construct(_Objty *_Ptr, _Types&&... _Args)
{   // construct _Objty(_Types...) at _Ptr
    ::new ((void *)_Ptr) _Objty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...); // here
}
```

But when I put all my code in main.cpp without modifying anything, the program works as expected.

When the thrown exception is triggered from running my code in the static library, the output points to (in red) Position, Color and TexCoords with these values:

```
Position x=0.0... y=4.059...e-34
Color x=7.119e-43#DEN y=4.0428...e-34 z=7.119e+34
TexCoord x 1.40...e+34 y=4.591e-41#DEN
```

Comment: Where in *your* code does the exception get thrown? Check the callstack.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 the call doesn't say specifically other than pointing to line 637 in xmemory0. My suspicion is there is a problem with  vertices being global.

Comment: You may be able to fix the issue by changing it to a simple array of structs if the vec2 and vec3 are POD types (see C++ definition of POD type) 
`const graphics::Vertex vertices[] =
        {
            { { -0.5f, -0.5f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f } },
            { { 0.5f, -0.5f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },{ 1.0f, 0.0f } },
            { { 0.5f, 0.5f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f } },
            { { -0.5f, 0.5f },{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f } }
        };`

Comment: There's little value in creating a constant ``std::vector`` anyhow. Create this as a old-style C array or as a ``std::array``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables and objects in different translation units (c++ / object files) do not have a guaranteed initialization order.

It is possible that your std::vector is being used by another global (or static) object constructor in another file before it is actually initialized.

Put all the dependent variables in order within the same file or initialize them in a controlled fashion some other way, such as inside an Init() function called from main but for this you will need to make it non-const.

Edit:
It's called the "static initialization order fiasco".

The C++ initialization steps in practice are:

1. null pointers / zero variables get initialized by the OS when loading the executable (BSS section)
2. Simple struct and classes (POD) and variables with non-zero values either get initialized by the OS during exectuable loading (DATA section) or on embedded systems by copying from ROM in the pre-main() code.
3. Constructors inside each object files get called in order where they are inside the files but no guarantee between individual object files.
4. main() gets called
5. main() returns
6. Destructors are called. It's supposed to be in reverse order but speaking from experience it's not always the case (yes, it's a compiler/linker/SDK bug when it happens but that doesn't change your project deadline.)

1 and 2 are called **static initialization**

Note that what is a POD type (Plain Old Data) varies according to what C++ standard you're using.

Something that is safe:

**FileA.cpp**

```
const char * const my_string = "ABC";
```

**FileB.cpp**

```
extern const char * const my_string;
std::string my_std_string (string);
```

`my_string` is a simple pointer that gets initialized by loading the DATA or RODATA segment before all constructors get called.

Something that depends on initialization order:

**FileA.cpp**

```
std::string my_std_string1("ABC");
```

**FileB.cpp**

```
extern std::string my_std_string1;
std::string my_std_string2 (my_std_string1);
```

If my_std_string2's constructor is called before my_std_string1 (the linker decides, different linkers pick different orders) it may copy garbage values or nulls depending on the system.